# Extracting Dates based on Months

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, select

I have a table in an MSSQL database that lists when students start a programme. The academic year runs from August to July.

Where a student starts on 01 Sep 2019 I want to show that they started in 19/20 If they start on 06 May 2020 I want to show they started in 19/20 If they start on 05 Aug 2020 I want to show they start in 20/21

I have tried to do this as a Case statement

```
SELECT 
   LEARNERID
  ,(
    CASE 
      WHEN datepart(MM, LEARNSTARTDATE) BETWEEN 8 AND 12
        THEN datepart(YY, LEARNSTARTDATE)
      END
    ) AS StartYear
  ,(
    CASE 
      WHEN datepart(MM, LEARNSTARTDATE) BETWEEN 1 AND 7
        THEN datepart(YY, LEARNSTARTDATE)
      END
    ) AS EndYear
FROM ILR
```

This is not working for me

Any help with this would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: To help us help you, please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61277698/edit) your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: add your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would offset the date by 6 month, and format it as follows:

```
format(dateadd(month, -6, learnstartdate), 'yy')
    + '/'
    + format(dateadd(month, 6, learnstartdate), 'yy')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5782f0bb77ec4d33de163bcd834c49a7)**:

```
select  
    learnstartdate, 
    format(dateadd(month, -6, learnstartdate), 'yy')
        + '/'
        + format(dateadd(month, 6, learnstartdate), 'yy') scholar_year
from (values('2019-09-01'), ('2020-05-06'), ('2020-08-05')) t(learnstartdate)
GO
```

```
learnstartdate | scholar_year
:------------- | :-----------
2019-09-01     | 19/20       
2020-05-06     | 19/20       
2020-08-05     | 20/21
```

Comment: Thanks for this help

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `EndYear` by adding 5 months to the date:

```
select LEARNERID, LEARNSTARTDATE, EndYear - 1 StartYear, EndYear
from (
  select LEARNERID, LEARNSTARTDATE, year(dateadd(month, 5, LEARNSTARTDATE)) EndYear
  from ILR  
) t
```

If you want the result in the format `XX/XX`:

```
select LEARNERID, LEARNSTARTDATE,
  format((EndYear - 1) % 100, '00') + '/' + format((EndYear) % 100, '00') AcademicYear
from (
  select LEARNERID, LEARNSTARTDATE, year(dateadd(month, 5, LEARNSTARTDATE)) EndYear
  from ILR  
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e5bfb8a5d6b681bc38f685cb04aa4473).
Results:

```
> LEARNERID | LEARNSTARTDATE | AcademicYear
> --------: | :------------- | :-----------
>         1 | 2019-09-01     | 19/20       
>         2 | 2020-05-06     | 19/20       
>         3 | 2020-08-05     | 20/21       
>         4 | 2019-08-01     | 19/20       
>         5 | 2019-07-31     | 18/19
```

Comment: @gillers322 it seems that you accepted the only answer of the 3 existing that is wrong as you can see here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b07ef080629edf62a389c96409efdc5c

Answer (score 1):

An option would be a `CASE...ELSE`, with a `MODULO (%)` to get the two digit year and a `CONCAT` to handle the data type conversion to strings.

```
SELECT 
   LEARNERID
  ,LEARNSTARTDATE
  ,CASE 
      WHEN datepart(MONTH, LEARNSTARTDATE) >= 8
        THEN CONCAT(datepart(YEAR, LEARNSTARTDATE) % 100 , '/', datepart(YEAR, LEARNSTARTDATE) % 100 + 1)
      ELSE CONCAT(datepart(YEAR, LEARNSTARTDATE) % 100 -1 , '/', datepart(YEAR, LEARNSTARTDATE) % 100)
    END AS RequestedOutput
FROM 
(
   VALUES (1,'2019-09-01'),(2,'2020-05-06'),(3,'2020-08-20')
) v(LEARNERID,LEARNSTARTDATE);
```

Results:

```
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+
| LEARNERID | LEARNSTARTDATE | RequestedOutput |
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+
|         1 | 2019-09-01     | 19/20           |
|         2 | 2020-05-06     | 19/20           |
|         3 | 2020-08-20     | 20/21           |
+-----------+----------------+-----------------+
```

[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/ZSBHG95881)

Comment: Thanks Eric - I am now spoilt for choice.